# I'm trying to parse json response of a php api in ajax call but getting bad escape character error

Tags: php, json, ajax, api, parsing

This error only occurs when I try to parse large JSON response, suppose 100+ records. I'm trying to parse JSON containing HINDI characters in response. I've tried validating the JSON response but no online tool shows any error in the response that I'm getting.

### Error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad escaped character at line 1 column 65529 of the JSON data
```

### AJAX Call

```
$.ajax(
            {
                url: "api/getPrintReport.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    fromDateLimit: dateVal,
                    toDateLimit: dateVal1,
                    reportType: selectedReportIndex,
                    cadreCode: cadreCode,
                    pageNo: startPageNo
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    //console.log(result);
                    const json = JSON.parse(result);
                    if (json['status'] === "1")
                    {
                        // doing something...
                    }
                    else {
                        modalBox.modal('show');
                        modalBoxMessage.html(json['message']);
                    }

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    modalBox.modal('show');
                    modalBoxMessage.html(errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

When i try to debug the code, the debugger never goes ahead of JSON.parse() method.

### JSON Response

```
{
"message": "Data retrieved successfully.",
"status": "1",
"currentPage": "1",
"totalPages": "4",
"data": [
    {
      // Around 10-15 key-value pairs
    },
    {}...more JSON objects here
]}
```

I've validated the JSON response with the help of some online tools but can't find any bad escape character or error in it. I'm only getting this error when I try to get more than 80 or 100 records. The code works perfectly when I parse lesser records. I'm using PostgreSQL as DB.

I even tried searching if there's a limit set for a response but I came to know that there's no limit until we set one, but in my case, I haven't set any limit. Please help me.

### Screenshot of Network Tool

[image: Here in the 1st line i'm getting a garbage/null character at the end.]

[image: the same character continues in the start of the 2nd line.]

Here in the 1st line, I'm getting a garbage/null character at the end.
The same character continues at the start of the 2nd line.

Comment: Please check your JSON data is in valid JSON format or not

Comment: How do you validate your JSON response...? Are you copy/pasting from the display of JSON data in the console...?

Comment: No, I'm not copying/pasting from the console, I'm copying/pasting from the postman tool where I'm getting a complete response from the API

Comment: Maybe somehow what's returned in the AJAX is different. Re-instate `console.log(result)` in your code and take a look. And/or look in the browser's network tool and find the raw response which comes back from the server in response to the AJAX request.

Comment: I've tried viewing the raw response in postman since it shows the Unicode characters and validated that response but it was a valid JSON response so the validator tool didn't showed any issue.

Comment: Ok. But again, because you're having problems it seems quite likely that what you're seeing in postman may be different somehow than what your browser is receiving via AJAX. That's why you need to check the data your AJAX code is actually working with, not the data you got from a separate request using a different tool.

Comment: ok let me just try what you are suggesting then I'll comment back.

Comment: @ADyson I've tried what you suggested but unfortunately, that also didn't work for me.

Comment: What do you mean? I just asked you to check some data. You will always be able to see it in the network tool (unless the request fails entirely), so I can't understand how that "didn't work", exactly? What did you discover when you looked?

Comment: @ADyson I've re-instated the console.log(result) and tried validating the response copied from the console. Can you please elaborate on what exactly you're suggesting to look in network tool.

Comment: You open the network tool, you run the code, you look for the AJAX request appearing. Then you click on the request and, in the area which opens up related to that specific request, you go to the Response tab. Then you can see the raw response exactly as it came from the server

Comment: `tried validating the response copied from the console`...ok, and did you see the same data you get when you do it in postman? Did it validate?

Comment: @ADyson that's where I guess the issue is the result variable in the ajax call never shows the complete data when I try to read the raw response. It shows partial data followed by ... 3 dots like this. so, obviously, it's not gonna be validated.

Comment: Well if it's very a large dataset it's possible the browser display has truncated it visually for some reason. Or it's possible (but perhaps less likely) that the server somehow generated such a response, I guess. What's the size of the response, is it very large?

Comment: @ADyson no, I'll not say it's very large compared to the postman response I'm getting but since it includes Hindi Unicode characters, there might be a possibility that the result variable is not getting a complete response since it's a string variable. May be it's limit is getting exceeded somehow, also the response size is less than 200 KBs.

Comment: Is your webpage set up to understand UTF-8?

Comment: @ADyson yes it does. I've added the meta tag on the page.

Comment: Hmm. 200KB can still be quite a lot of text. But I must say it's hard to see what might be the issue. Can you provide a screenshot of the network tool showing this truncated response?

Comment: 200KB of json data should be nothing for any computer with more than 2gigs of ram and was made after 2001. If you're deadset on parsing the json instead of specifying the dataType in the ajax parameters... then try $.parseJSON(result) instead and see if that plays nice.

Comment: @ADyson I've posted the screenshot of the network tool please check and suggest how can i remove this character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to parse the json... try this

```
$.ajax(
            {
                url: "api/getPrintReport.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json', //<---------- TELL THE SERVER YOU WANT JSON
                data: {
                    fromDateLimit: dateVal,
                    toDateLimit: dateVal1,
                    reportType: selectedReportIndex,
                    cadreCode: cadreCode,
                    pageNo: startPageNo
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    //console.log(result);
                    //const json = JSON.parse(result);
                    if (result.status === "1")
                    {
                        // doing something...
                    }
                    else {
                        modalBox.modal('show');
                        modalBoxMessage.html(json['message']);
                    }

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    modalBox.modal('show');
                    modalBoxMessage.html(errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

Comment: I've already tried doing that. What happens is the control directly goes into the error block instead of going into the success block and shows the same error into the model dialog box.

Comment: okay... so then in getPrintReport.php are you setting `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`? are you also making sure to `echo json_encode($someDataToReturn); exit;`?

Comment: yes, i've added the header and making sure to echo json_encode($someDataToReturn); exit;

Comment: what happens if you force the encoding? `echo json_encode(array_map('utf8_encode', $someDataToReturn))`

Comment: haven't tried it yet. will try and let you know.

Comment: Did you have any luck with forcing encoding?

Comment: No, that didn't work for me. But finally, something that worked for me is using the JQuery DataTable plugin to display the data in a table and exactly the way I wanted to show it. Before I was using HTML Table. I don't know how those characters were coming in my JSON response but now I'm not having any issues after using the data table plugin. Thank you for your help.

Comment: glad you were able to figure it out :)